# PyQt - can't read Excel file

Tags: excel, pandas, pyqt, signals-slots, pyqt6

I'm trying to make GUI application for getting data out of Excel about lognormal distribution and making some graph data.
My code looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QTabWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
import pandas as pd


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.btnShow.setEnabled(False)
        self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browseFiles)
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(lambda: self.loadExcelData(self.filename.text()))

    @Slot()
    def browseFiles(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Excel file', 'C:\\', "Excel (*.xls *.xlsx)")
        # fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open CSV file', 'C:\\', "CSV (*.csv)")
        self.filename.setText(fname[0])

    @Slot()
    def loadExcelData(self, pathOfFile):
        column_names = ["IDofCell", "SerialNumber", "Action", "TimeOfFailure", "ReverseRankR", "Cdf", "Ppf", "LogTime"]
        df = pd.read_excel(pathOfFile, names=column_names)
        if df.size == 0:
            return
        self.tableExcelData.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableExcelData.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.tableExcelData.setHorizontalHearsLabels(df.columns)



# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    mainWidget.addWidget(mainWindow)
    mainWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

"Gui.ui" looks something like this:
[image: Menu - file browsing, buttons for operations]

[image: Excel data - basically QTableWidget content]

The problem on which I occured is happening when I'm trying to read Excel file after clicking "Load Data" it freezes and after moment... it crashes.
Excel data from the file I'm uploading:

[[image: Example look for my Excel data3]

I don't know why it crashes (only that it crashes at read_excel line). If you know solution to this problem and you can share it with me I would be very grateful.

Comment: I see a typo: `setHorizontalHearsLabels` should be [`setHorizontalHeaderLabels`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setHorizontalHeaderLabels). Besides, try to run the program in a terminal or prompt to see if there's some debug output, and eventually [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Hi @musicamante,
Yeah, I corrected the error (I got no info when working with Pycharm, I had to look at it closely to see the bug).
I also found out that I couldn't read from Excel file due to not having "openpyxl" package. I added it to the project after installing and it works now. :)